# How set cursor to end text in field of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I set value of field:

```
    dataGridV.SelectedCells[0].Value = "any text";
    // DataGridView.SelectedCells[0] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
```

But cursor moves to the beginning of the text. How to move the cursor to the end of the text?